How can I close established SSH connections after shutting down SSHd server on Windows?
I recently installed the OpenSSH server and OpenSSH client that come with Windows 11.
When I turn off the server, any incoming ssh requests are rejected, as they should be. But, already established connections would stay running despite turning off the server, disabling port forwarding, etc.
I confirmed the established connections still being active by using the netstat -an | sls ':22'  command and seeing the established connections still being up. Commands that rely on ssh like scp continue downloading over an established SSH connection as well.
Is there a way I can (forcibly) disconnect established connections from the server side ssh on windows?
I would prefer to be able to shut down certain established connections based on their IP or based on user login or even all of them at once, but anything would be great.
Additonal information:
Usually I start the server using Start-Service sshd and close the server using Stop-Service sshd. I confirm the server has been stopped using Get-Service -Name sshd, which shows the server has been stopped after using the Stop-Service sshd command.

When I turn off the server should be changed to When I stop the service, unless you are actually seeing packets flowing through a physically shut down machine... which would be interesting, to say the least.

Is there a different way to turn off the server other than stopping the service?

Is the process still running? Can you kill it?

How can I find the process and kill it?

I mean, "turn off the server" is usually intended as "turn off the MACHINE".

I think the answer will be "exactly as in any other system": tasklist | find sshd followed by taskkill, or whatever their powershell equivalents would be. Also notice that bound authenticated sshd runs under the authenticated user, so that way you see whose this session is.

Upd: to kill all of them at once, try taskkill /im sshd.exe.
